# OpenLayers 3 drag box interaction not pointing correctly

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using OpenLayers 3.9.0. I Want to add and remove dragZoom and dragBox interactions in OpenLayers 3 map dynamically.

```
<button id='box'>dragBox</button>

var dragBox = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
            condition: ol.events.condition.always,
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: [0, 0, 255, 1]
                })
            })
        });
```

In jQuery for button click event:

```
$('#box').click(function(){
    map.addInteraction(dragBox);
})
```

When this event triggered using button the cursor and the box are not at same position.

[image: Displaced mouse position]

So why does this is happen, and how can we overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

It is due to the change of the size of map container externally. It is fixed by adding the function to update the map size whenever the size of the map container(div) has changed externally

```
map.updateSize();
```

This function updates the size of the map container dynamically. So the pointer points exactly